# "is not a function" type error inside $scope.$on

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I ran into a specific problem working with Angular. I have a parent controller named **uploadController** that has a **validateFiles** function to validate the uploaded files.

On a button click from UI , a modal popup is opening there I can input some values. On submit of that form I want to invoke that validateFiles method which is on other controller(the name of modal controller is **UserUploadDataCtrl** with the input data from the UI modal form).

I thought $rootScope.$broadcast in UserUploadDataCtrl and $scope.$on in uploadController would be great.

What I did is ...

```
if ($scope.groupMembershipUserInputForm.$valid) {
    $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams = {
        "chapterCode": $scope.groupmembership.chapterCode,
        "groupCode": $scope.groupmembership.groupCode,
        "createdDate": $filter('date')(new Date($scope.groupmembership.createdDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
        "endDate": $filter('date')(new Date($scope.groupmembership.endDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
    }

    $rootScope.$broadcast('validateUploadedFilesEvent', $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams);
```

and then in **uploadController**

```
// NOW VALIDATE THE UPLOADED THE FILES.
$scope.$on('validateUploadedFilesEvent', function (event, arg) {
    UploadDataServices.setUploadParams(arg);
    $scope.validateFiles();
});
```

It says **UploadDataServices.setUploadParams(arg)** is not a function.

But I have used it many times the same way .

```
UploadModule.factory('UploadDataServices', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$filter', function ($http, $rootScope, $filter) {


    var uploadParams = null;

    return {

        setUploadValidationResult: function (result) {
            uploadValidationResultData = result;
        },

        getUploadValidationResult: function () {
            return uploadValidationResultData;
        },


        setUploadParams: function (params) {
            uploadParams = params;
        },

        getUploadParams: function () {
            return uploadParams;
        }
```

....

Where am I doing wrong?

Here is the error

[image]

Here is the uploadController definition

```
UploadModule.controller('GroupMembershipUploadController', ['$scope', '$location', '$log', 
    '$window', '$localStorage', 'mainService', '$state', '$rootScope', '$http', '$uibModal', '$uibModalStack', 'uiGridConstants', 'UploadDataServices', 'UploadServices',
function ($scope, $location, $log, $window, $localStorage, mainService, $state, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, $uibModalStack, uiGridConstants, UploadDataServices, UploadServices) {
```

Comment: How you are injecting `UploadDataServices`? Can you show the code for `GroupMembershipUploadController`?

Comment: Please find the updated details.

Comment: What is `UploadDataServices` at the time your trying to call the method? If you `console.log` it. Are you doing anything fancy with with in your controller or just consuming its methods/properties?

Comment: @ste2425 .. nothing fancy . Whatever data I got back from broadcast I wanted to store in the service , later on to use it . That's why I called setUploadParams(arg) where the arg is the data I received from the service.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder can you add jsfiddle link what have you done yet?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(UploadDataServices)` in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer to your problem but I would suggest structuring your code differently. I've added it as an answer as this is too much for a comment.

In my opinion, the modal controller should only manage the lifecycle of the modal itself (close, cancel) passing a result back to the instance if needed.

The modal html should include an upload component. The upload component controller can have the upload data service injected and use it directly.

Apart from the separation of concerns, another benefit is that you can now do uploads independently of the modal (should you wish to).

You may be aware that services are singletons. Spreading your use case across multiple calls to the service may be considered a code smell and might encounter problems if it were servicing more than one controller.

For example,

**Modal controller**

For example, let the modal controller handle the form being cancelled. Using this pattern you could handle other actions from the form such as close.

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('ModalCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  'use strict';

  // handle a cancel on the form
  $scope.cancel = function () { 
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };

});
```

**Modal html**

```
<div class="deposit-funds">
  <upload cancel="cancel()"></upload>
</div>
```

**Upload directive**

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('upload', function() {
  'use strict';
  return {
    ...
    'scope': {
      cancel: '&?' // let the modal controller close the modal on cancel
    },
    'controller': 'UploadCtrl',
    ...
  };
});
```

**Upload controller**

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('UploadCtrl', function (uploadService) {
  var that = this;

  that.submit = function () {
    uploadService.doStuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would agree with the commenter in that the modal controller should handle the lifecycle of the modal and pass the data back to the originating controller.